# How to calculate this surface integral?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, integration, moment-of-inertia

I was calculating a triangle's moment of inertia, and I got stuck. I've found this on the internet:

$$\theta =\iiint \limits _{V}r^{2}(x,y,z)\,\rho (x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz\!$$

My triangle is only 2 dimensional, so I "removed" the $z$, and got:

$$\theta =\iint \limits _{A}r^{2}(x,y)\,\rho (x,y)\,dx\,dy\!$$

Since the mass distribution is constant, $\rho(x,y)=constant$, I've got something like this:

$$\theta =\rho \iint \limits _{A}\left( (s_x-x)^2+(s_y-y)^2\,\right) \,dx\,dy\!$$

And what could I do with this? I was thinking about integrating it from x=0 to the furthest x coordinate, and same with the y, but that would give me a rectangle, I think.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate this about an arbitrary axis of rotation? What is the direction of the axis?

Comment: The axis of rotation is normal to the surface, and goes through the centre of gravity, S(s_x, s_y). And also 3S=A+B+C

Comment: I would use the perpendicular axis theorem. Compute the moment of inertia about an axis through a vertex, and again about the axis at right angles to that. The moment of inertia about the perpendicular axis is the sum of these two. With this setup it will be easier to construct the right limits for the integral.

Comment: One of your integration boundaries needs to depend on $x$ (or on $y$).

Comment: Thanks @Floris. So i should use the perpendicular axis theorem for the vertex on the (0,0), and move the normal movement to the inertia with parallel theorem to the mass of gravity, instead of the surface integral, right?

Comment: @user1583209, i think the surface depends on both x and y.

Comment: What I mean is that if you have a triangle you can chose your coordinates such that one side is along one of the axis (say along the $x$-axis). The other two sides then can be viewed as a piecewise linear function $y(x)$. Integration boundaries are then from $0$ to $y(x)$ for the integration over $y$ and from $0$ to $x_\mathrm{max}$ (i.e. assuming the corners of the triangle are at (0,0) and ($x_\mathrm{max}$,0)) for integration over $x$.

Comment: "I" is always UPPERCASE in English...

Comment: @peterh chill brother

Comment: @SaudiBombsYemen Ok. But it looks really badly. It looks really badly. Here you are talking mainly with people whose native language has capital letters and it looks really badly for them. Consider this as a deal: 1) you have to press the "shift" key 2) you will make *much* better impression. I think it is a good deal. (P.s. We know what is going in Yemen, although it has not a central place in the news, and we aren't happy. Unfortunately, the sad truth is that the people has not really more saying here in the politics as by you.)